# I have table and I want to export my table data in excel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Currently in my page it give me print after click button but I want get data in excel

```
<form role="form" id="print_cash_challan" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <section class="content">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="table-responsive">
           <table id="gst_reporttable" class="table table-bordered  table-sm" style=" overflow: auto;">  </table>
          </div>
     </div>
    </section>
  </form>
<button id="print" name="print"  onclick="printContent('print_cash_challan')" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-primary fa fa-newspaper-o col-10 offset-1" style="margin-top: 35px; margin-bottom: 25px;" data-clicked="unclicked"> print Gst Report</button>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    var from_date_bk       = "<?php echo isset($_POST['from_date_bk'])? $_POST['from_date_bk'] : '';  ?>";
    var to_date_bk         = "<?php echo isset($_POST['to_date_bk'])? $_POST['to_date_bk'] : '';  ?>";

    $.ajax({
     url :"<?php echo base_url(); ?>gst/GstController/printGstReport",
     type: 'POST', 
     async:false,              
     data: {
      from_date_bk:from_date_bk,
      to_date_bk:to_date_bk,

     },
     dataType: "html",
     success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $('#gst_reporttable').html(data);
     },
     error:function(data){
      console.log('error occured during fetch');
      /*alertify.error("error message"+data);*/
     }
  });
});

     function printContent(e1) {
     event.preventDefault();

      var restorepage     = document.innterHTML;
      var printContent    = document.getElementById(e1).innterHTML;
      document.innterHTML = printContent;
      window.print();
      document.location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"; 
      location.href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>gst/GstController/gstReportPage", 'refresh';
   }
</script>
```

I have table on my controller. 
In above code I use window.print() for print.
I do not know to export in excel.

Comment: What I can do in this code

Comment: you have to write it ... - Since you didn't provide anything - i would go for https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and study it ....

Answer (score 1):

Try this example

```
<?php
    $data = array(
        array("First Name" => "Abc 1", "Last Name" => "Abc 2", "Email" => "Abc1@gmail.com"),
        array("First Name" => "Abc 2", "Last Name" => "Abc 2", "Email" => "Abc2@gmail.com")
    );

    function filterData(&$str)
    {
        $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
        $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
        if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
    }

    // file name for download
    $fileName = "new" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

    // headers for download
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\"");
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

    $flag = false;
    foreach($data as $row) {
        if(!$flag) {
            // display column names as first row
            echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
            $flag = true;
        }
        // filter data
        array_walk($row, 'filterData');
        echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";

    }
    exit;
?>
```